# How to read JSON from file and replace objects with value?

Tags: java, json

I need to read JSON from file and replace few objects.

For example, I have class User.java

```
public class User {
    String username;
    String email;
    String city;
    String code;
    }
```

and JSON:

```
{
    "variables":

        {

        "user":

            {

            "value":

            {

            "username": "$USERNAME",        
            "email": "$EMAIL",   
            "city": "$CITY"
            } 
        }

    }

}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I read JSON from file? Read JSON will be send by WebClient POST API.
2. How can I replace $USERNAME, $EMAIL and $CITY? I won't hardcode it.
   I have register form. When someone complete form, it will be replaced for $...

Firsty, I got hardcode JSON to string but I need read it from file

```
class JSONClass {
    static String toFormat(User user) {
        String jsonUserRegister = "{\n" +
                "    \"variables\":\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "           \"user\": \n" +
               "           {\n" +
                "               \"value\":\n" +
                "                   {\n" +
               "                \"username\": \"" + user.getUsername() + "\",\n" +
               "                \"email\": \"" + user.getEmail() + "\",\n" +
               "                \"city\": \"" + user.getCity() + "\",\n" +
                "                \"code\": \"" + user.getCode() + "\"\n" +
               "               } }\n" +
              "        }\n" +
               "}";

       return jsonUserRegister;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Spring Boot to set up the backend to receive client calls. So to get Task 1a working, we need below

```
@RestController
public class JsonReaderController {

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

@PostMapping(value = "/read-json")
public String fileContent() throws IOException {
    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(
            resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:data/json- sample.json").getFile().toPath()));
  }
}
```

Above code simply reads file content and returns as String. **Note default response is Json.**

Now that we have the backend done, we need **Task 1b - Sending the POST request**.

```
private String readJsonFile() throws IOException {
    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    final String requestUrl = "http://localhost:8080/read-json";

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(requestUrl)
            .post(RequestBody.create(JSON, ""))
            .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        //we know its not empty given scenario
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

**readJsonFile** method makes a POST request - using OkHttp to our backend bit (done in Task 1a) and returns the content of the file as json.

And for Task 2 - **replacing $USERNAME, $EMAIL and $CITY with appropriate values**. For this, we will use the Apache commons-text library.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileContent = new ReadJsonFromFile().readJsonFile();

    User user = new User("alpha", "alpha@tesrt.com", "Bristol", "alpha");

    Map<String, String> substitutes = new HashMap<>();
    substitutes.put("$USERNAME", user.getUsername());
    substitutes.put("$EMAIL", user.getEmail());
    substitutes.put("$CITY", user.getCity());
    substitutes.put("$CODE", user.getCode());

    StringSubstitutor stringSubstitutor = new StringSubstitutor(substitutes);

    //include double quote prefix and suffix as its json wrapped
    stringSubstitutor.setVariablePrefix("\"");
    stringSubstitutor.setVariableSuffix("\"");

    String updatedContent = stringSubstitutor.replace(fileContent);

    System.out.println(updatedContent);
}
```

Hope this helps.